Designing a MongoDB Database for a Spreadsheet-like Application with Mergeable Cells
I'm working on a project to create a web application similar to Excel, where users can edit cells in a spreadsheet. I need help designing the database schema using MongoDB to support the following features:

Editable Cells: Users should be able to edit the content of individual cells.

Merge/Unmerge Cells: Users should be able to merge multiple cells into one and later unmerge them.

Persistent State: The state of the cells (including merged cells) should be saved so that users see the same configuration when they return to the page|
How can I design a MongoDB schema to handle these requirements effectively? Any advice on best practices or potential pitfalls would be greatly appreciated.


I was thinking about a collection for the spreadsheets and another for the cells, but I'm not sure how to represent merged cells. Here's a rough idea:
{
  "spreadsheets": [
    {
      "_id": "spreadsheet_id",
      "name": "Spreadsheet 1",
      "cells": [
        {
          "cell_id": "A1",
          "content": "Data",
          "merged_with": ["A2", "A3"]
        },
        {
          "cell_id": "A2",
          "content": "",
          "merged_with": ["A1", "A3"]
        },
        {
          "cell_id": "A3",
          "content": "",
          "merged_with": ["A1", "A2"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

